# XSS prevention when inserting HTML without user controlled data into the DOM?

Tags: xss, html, ajax

I have some JavaScript that fetches some HTML from a PHP script, and inserts it into the DOM:

```
$.get("/includes/blocks.php",{
  id:encodeURIComponent(id)
}).done(function(Data){
  $('<div class="pac">'+Data.html+'</div>').appendTo('.main');
});
```

What is the best way to prevent XSS if I want insert HTML code from `blocks.php` into the DOM? It contains a lot of HTML elements with tons of attributes. No user controlled data is returned, but could the returning data be modified somehow?

Comment: Are there any user-controlled parameters involved?

Comment: (Or is the content of `blocks.php` untrusted?)

Comment: @Arminius updated the question. The content of PHP file is mine with no user-controlled params, but could the returing data be modified by someone?

Comment: @Anders, the question is updated

Comment: Watch out RFI with includes if you want a where user/attacker can inject code form https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Testing_for_Remote_File_Inclusion

Comment: Just to be clear here: `blocks.php` doesn't fetch any data from a database containing data from users, or anything of the sort?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> No user controlled data is returned, but could the returning data be modified somehow?

No, you're safe. You're fetching a document from a fixed URL (`/includes/blocks.php`) on the same origin which reflects no user-controlled data. For it to be vulnerable to XSS, you'd need an entry point where the attacker can inject code, but at no point does the your code even handle user input.